# Implement search by preference in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's imagine we have trivial structure's hotel and user.

```
Hotel          User
-----          ----
Id             Id 
Name           Name
```

I have additional information presenting how particular user likes particular hotel. Which may be presented like:

```
Preferences
-----------
hotel_id
user_id
tier (int value, 0-9)
```

Let's agree that number of hotels is more than 1M.

Search we need to run each time is **get first 10 hotel sorted by tier asc or desc**. 
Which Elasticsearch schema (indices, mapping, queries) would you recommend for this?

p.s. I know this is trivial for SQL, but I'm got in stuck with ES implementation.

Comment: tier is per user. So you want it for a particular user?

Comment: @Richa yes, sorting for particular user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query from `preferences` index:

```
{
"size": 10, 
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
           {
               "term": {
                     "user_id": "USERID"
               }
           }
        ]
    }
},
"sort": [
   {
      "tier": {
         "order": "desc"
      }
   }
  ]
}
```

If you want to get `hotel_name` add `hotel_name` field in `preferences` index and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, however, Can I get the hotel names here, in the same request?

Comment: I think that won't be possible according to current `index` structure. But if you store `hotel_name` in `preferences` index, you will get `hotel_name` as well.